# Is is possible to get your code and assets stolen

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am using kamcord framework that helps me record my game play on the app im developing. Is it possible for my stuff to get stolen? What are some good ways to improve security?

Comment: What does the framework and recording gameplay have to do with having your code and assets stolen? I don't understand your question. What is "your stuff"?

Comment: does a framework have access to your files and can it send them remotely

Comment: Nobody is going to steal anything from you. Not until you've made at least a fairly good app.

Answer (score 4):

Since your final application is compiled, it is not really possible to have your exact code stolen.  Assets can be retrieved from the .app file of your application, though.  If you're recording a video of your application, none of the above is possible.